# Python count number of strings in a list of variable types, without loop if possible

Tags: python, string, list, counting

would like to count number of strings in list of variable types, without a loop if possible:

```
l = [1,2,3,'a','b']
c = l.count(str)
print (c)
```

output:

```
0
```

expected output:

```
2
```

Comment: `list(map(type, l)).count(str)`, but a loop would be cleaner.

Comment: @vaultah that was fast, thank you, I guess this produces a list of types in l so that .count(str) can actually count types?

Comment: `sum([1 for x in l if type(x) == str])`  or `sum(1 for x in l if type(x) == str)` if you are looking to not create a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Guido isn't a big fan of `map` and `filter`, I'll give an answer that avoids them:

```
len([v for v in k if isinstance(v, str)])
```

This counts only the ones that are strings. It's wasteful because it builds an entire list in memory. There's no way to cleanly get the length of a generator, but there are hacks.

```
sum(isinstance(v, str) for v in k)
```

This works because the sum of booleans is the number of `True` values, so it's the number of strings. Credit to vaultah's comment for clarification.

Comment: Is it necessary to build a list just to count occurrences?

Comment: Oh, absolutely not. I would argue that your method is both more beautiful and efficient; I just want to give alternatives.

Comment: I wasn't referring to my code -- it actually creates a list, too. Since you chose to use an explicit loop, you could do `sum(isinstance(v, str) for v in k)`, which should be at least memory-efficient.

Answer (score -2):

My solution is probably a bit tedious but here's my try

```
l = [1,2,3,'a','b']
```

Join all the elements of the list in a single string

```
ll = ''.join(map(str,l))
```

Then do a count on it

```
letters = sum(c.isalpha() for c in ll)
```

Comment: Your code returns `3` for `[1,2,3,'a','ab']` which might not be the intended behavior. Also, you mean `ll = ''.join(map(str,l))`, don't you?

Comment: Hi @frederick99, my code works for what OP asked ;). Thanks for the amendment.

Comment: _count the number of strings in a list_. I don't think your code does that! You are welcome. ;)